# Recover URL Parameter Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-route

My front sends parameters in the url and I would like to get them back to my laravel controller.

My route (back)

```
Route::get('publication/Mls/{status}/{typeTransac}', 'MlsController@getIndicatorMlsList');
```

The console shows me this on the front side

[api/user/publication/Mls?status=Archive&typeTransac=Vente](http://api/user/publication/Mls?status=Archive&typeTransac=Vente)

How do I get this information back?

Comment: Its `Mls?` or `Mls/`?

Comment: Its just publication/Mls?param1&param2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they are not the same route. you have to change either in front end or back end. the front end url is

```
api/user/publication/Mls?status=Archive&typeTransac=Vente
```

in this url `api/user/publication/Mls` is the base url and `?status=Archive&typeTransac=Vente` is request parameter. to get it in the laravel side you need a route like

```
Route::get('publication/Mls', 'MlsController@getIndicatorMlsList');
```

assuming you have `user` prefixed in your route. if not you have to add that too in your route.

now in your controller you can access the request parameter

```
public function getIndicatorMlsList (Request $request)
{
    $status = $request->status;
    $typeTransac = $request->typeTransac;
}
```

or you can keep your back end route as same as it is now and change the front end url

```
api/user/publication/Mls/Archive/Vente
```

and in the controller

```
public function getIndicatorMlsList ($status, $typeTransac)
{
    //the function parameters are the values from the url
}
```

Comment: Ok Angular send api/user/publication/Mls?status=Archive&typeTransac=Vente And Laravel take parameters "status" and "typeTransac" and do  public function getProducts($status, $date, $typeTransac, $productsMlsId)
{
        $arrayIdProducts = ProductCritereCache::select('products_id')
        ->where('121', $status)
                //products_date_added > date

        ->where('products_date_added', '>', $date)
        ->where('28', $typeTransac)
        ->where('products_id', $productsMlsId)
        ->get()
        ->pluck('products_id')
        return $arrayIdProducts;
}

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this

```
public function getIndicatorMlsList($status, $typeTransac){
    // your rest code
}
```